# Чатлане общаются или разговаривают?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, чат

В правой части страницы наблюдается (как я понял, только для Меты) блок с указанием кол-ва человек, присутствующих в чатах:

> [image: 80]

> [image: 171]

Как видно по картинкам, иногда они "общаются", но порой и "разговаривают".

Всё это потому, что в transifex исходная строка:

> [$num$ People Chatting](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261796?key=9cb971b40cb463eb499299c67c3a06cd)

Имеет существенно различающиеся переводы в зависимости от числа `$num$`:

- one

  > $num$ человек разговаривает
- few

  > $num$ человека общается
- many

  > $num$ человек общаются

Просто изменить форму для `one` в соответствии с остальными двумя я, конечно, могу, но сам перевод и его звучание меня как-то [смущают](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/427365/183872).

Поэтому предлагаю обсудить более приемлемые варианты.

Comment: единичная форма - `$one$ человек разговаривает` - это шизофрения :)

Comment: @kami эта форма актуальна и для 21,31 и т.д.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Но все равно в исходном тексте вопроса "One" как бы недвусмысленно намекает на одного разговаривающего человека. Я не придираюсь, просто улыбнуло.

Comment: @kami свой вариант не хотите предложить?

Comment: @alexolut , а если просто написать: количество участников в чатах $num$

Comment: @perfect Вам текущая выбранная форма чем-то не нравится?

Comment: @alexolut все устраивает. просто я смотрю на это с целью упрощения логики. это всего лишь мысли в слух.

Comment: @perfect логика там не меняется. Там всего лишь строка с единственной переменной.

Comment: @alexolut я подумал выбор окончаний должен зависить от числа. тогда судя английскому варианту, должно быть: $num$ общающихся людей в чатах.

Comment: @perfect он и зависит.

Comment: @alexolut я всмысле про то что код автоматически подставит нужное окончание в зависимости от $num$. Я бы не стал использовать шаблон для мозговой подстановки самого участника (это формальность и пережиток прошлых дней проявившийся из за бумажной волокиты). Лучше пусть мозг вычислит разницу чем запустит перебор, это для человека естественней.

Comment: @perfect что-то я не понял про мозг. Свой вариант отдельным ответом не хотите озвучить для прояснения ситуации?

Comment: @alexolut попробую ответить но я уже боюсь умничать на этом проекте здесь почему то креативное мышление почему то не приветствуют ))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, такой вариант (с учётом множественных форм):

> $num$ участник/а/ов в чатах

---

Утвердил на transifex. Ждём подкачки базы и обновления сайта.

Comment: Мне "участники" напоминают "количество зарегистрированных пользователей" на сайте. А здесь, насколько понимаю, нужен аналог для "находятся на сайте прямо сейчас". "Общаются" или "разговаривают" звучало и точнее, и менее официально.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky всё что могу сказать: предлагайте свои варианты для обсуждения.

Answer (score 0):

Значит имеем строку вида:

```
число строка
```

**число** может принимать натуральный ряд чисел включая нуль

**строка** указывает на количество человек в чатах указанное в числе, при этом необходимо чтобы строка принимала правильную количественную форму.

мне бы хотелось что бы при чтении данной конструкции мозг затратил минимум усилий.

в случае ответа который предложил alexolut

```
$num$ участник/а/ов в чатах
```

мозг делает так:

```
1 прочитать число
2 определить количество
3 прочитать первый вариант шаблона
4 сопоставить его с количеством
5 проверить на совпадение
6 при не совпадении повторять с пункта 3 но для следующего шаблона с другим окончанием
```

... тут цикл работы перебора (возможно что максимально добавится еще восемь дополнительных пунктов)

Я предлагаю такой вариант:

```
$num$ общающихся людей в чатах
```

ИЛИ

```
$num$ людей в чатах
```

мозг делает так:

```
1 прочитать число
2 определить количество
3 прочитать один единственный шаблон
4 сопоставить количество к предложенному шаблону
```

... тут надо учитывать что слово **люди** имеет только множественную форму и других вариантов не имеет, именно эту форму и имеет английский вариант.

если есть возможность **поменять** местами число и строку то я бы сделал так:

```
количество людей в чатах $num$
```

проще говоря не надо из человеческого мозга делать брутфорс, потому что это не эффективно )

Comment: возможно я не понял, но сообщение вида *2 общающихся людей в чатах* мне *взрывает* мозг

Comment: Вы бы хоть проверили как оно сейчас на сайте.

Comment: @Bald я привел пример исходя из того что число можно поставить только впереди строки. но это синтаксическая конструкция правильная. Если есть возможность поменять местами число и строку то я бы написал так: количество людей в чатах $num$

Comment: @Bald немного изменил ответ.

Comment: @alexolut немного изменил ответ.

Comment: @Bald я не знаю может только я так читаю: 2 - в множественном числе это двое (4 пункт), а не два.

Comment: Вы же так и не проверили, как оно сейчас на сайте, не так ли?

Comment: @alexolut а зачем проверять? вы же написали в ответе `Ждём подкачки базы и обновления сайта.` я откуда знаю какая сейчас версия? новая или старая ...

Comment: @perfect Вы сначала проверьте, а потом продолжим обсуждение, если будет в этом смысл ещё.

Comment: @alexolut да нет уже смысла. последний комментарий я просто принципиально написал, а проверил еще до этого. просто вы в комментариях под вопросом не разобрались и предложили прокомментировать ответом. я ответил из вежливости и теперь оказался не правым с вашей точки зрения. вот так я сейчас вижу всю ситуацию. ладно алекс я сейчас просто свой ответ удалю и все будут счастливы (то же кстати по принцыпу: если я этого не вижу значит этого нет)