# Отображение блока чата на главном сайте

Tags: предложение, чат

После недавнего [вопроса про участников чата](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4336/) и несколько более старого [о привлечении людей в чат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3983/), я подумал: а не стоит ли добавить отображение блока:

> [image: 80]

на основной (не Мета) сайт? Это однозначно позволит увеличить кол-во осведомленных о наличии чата людей. Мне кажется это можно довольно легко реализовать, и сама реализация не так навязчива для участников как в прежнем предложении.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, ссылка на чат присутствует на сайтах в бета стадии. Задача в этом случае, на мой взгляд, та же, что и при наличии ссылки на чат на Мете после прохождения аттестации – вовлечь участников в обсуждения правил сообщества.

Comment: Наличие ссылки на чат в боковой панели основного сайта после прохождения аттестации может иметь отрицательный эффект: вопросы с основного сайта мигрируют в чат.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky может иметь, а может и наоборот. В любом случае, популярность чата это повысит. Задающих вопросы в чате (когда можно и следует задать нормальный вопрос на сайте) можно отправлять обратно на сайт. Если есть возможность это проверить, то было бы неплохо сделать и посмотреть на результат - как изменится кол-во участников в чате и кол-во задаваемых вопросов на сайте.

Comment: Уже уточняю возможность. Надеюсь, ближе к рабочему дню в Штатах узнаем :) Как минимум, если нам очень хочется популяризировать чат, можно сделать баннер.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как дела?